# I am using AutoJsContext in geckobrowser with that I am using evaluate scrpit. But now i am using webview2 is there a how can i get this

Tags: wpf, webview2, gecko, geckofx

I am using AutoJsContext in geckobrowser with that I am using evaluate scrpit and asble to get data. But now i am using webview2 is there a how can i get this.

Gecko browser:

```
using (AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(browser.Window))
{
    var userIdResult = context
        .EvaluateScript("userId", (nsIDOMWindow)browser.Window.DomWindow);
}
```

Above is the code I use in gecko browser. now i need to get user id from webview2. Please help me in this issue

I am not able to get any alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.executescriptasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1418.22) to inject script into the current top-level document of the WebView2 and receive the result as a JSON string. The method doesn't have a way to specify an execution context. Script is executed in the global context of the top-level document similar to running script in the console of DevTools in the browser.

For example something like the following:

```
var resultAsJSON = await coreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync('window.userId');
```

Comment: when using the given line not getting the details
var resultAsJSON = coreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync('window.userId');  

This is the response getting from resultAsJSON
Id = 3461, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"

Comment: I've added the await I forgot.